# javascript deep copy members from array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I have a array of objects, looks like

```
[
  {Time: , //time stamp 
   psi:  //pressure value at the time
  }, 
  ... //other objects in the array the same
]
```

The array is named "data"

if I slice part of the array, and pass them to find local max and min values, would the code below deep copy and return the local extremes? How to verify?

```
var extreme = findLocalExtreme(data.slice(0, 10));  //slice(0, 10) for example, shallow copy

function findLocalExtreme(slicedArr){
  //error control skipped, the array could be empty or only 1 member
  let tempMax = slicedArr[0]; //would the "=" deep copy the object or just shallow copy? 
  let tempMin = slicedArr[0];
  let slicedArrLength = slicedArr.length;
  for (let i = 1; i < slicedArrLength; i++){
    if (slicedArr[i].psi > tempMax.psi){
      tempMax = slicedArr[I]; //deep copy or shallow copy?
    }
    if (slicedArr[i].psi < tempMin.psi){
      tempMin = slicedArr[i];
    }
  }
  return {
    Max: tempMax, 
    Min: tempMin //is the value assignment in returned class deep copy, or still shallow copy?
  }
}
```

Any advise welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`let tempMax = slicedArr[0]`
will just do the shallow copy instead you can do
 `let tempMax = {...slicedArr[0]}`
since your object is only at level one this will do a deepcopy,
if it is nested you can use loadash's cloneDeep to do a deepcopy.

Anywhere you are assiging a object to a variable it is a shallow copy

Answer (score 2):

You can use `loadsh` `cloneDeep` method to copy objects or array.

```
import _ from 'loadsh';
let arr = [
            {name: 'temp'}
            {name: 'temp1}
       ]

let copyArr = _.cloneDeep(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Deep Copy of a nested array of objects using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(your_array_here))`

[reference link Deep Copy & Shallow Copy](https://medium.com/@gamshan001/javascript-deep-copy-for-array-and-object-97e3d4bc401a#:%7E:text=The%20JSON.-,stringify()%20method%20converts%20a%20JavaScript%20value%20to%20a%20JSON,object%20described%20by%20the%20string.&text=This%20is%20also%20solution%20for%20deep%20copy%20objects%20inside%20array.,-%2F%2FDeep%20Clone)

```js
//Deep Clone
let a = [{ x:{z:1} , y: 2}];
let b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));
b[0].x.z=0
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```